# Различия в отображении сайта

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой отображения сайта, а именно отображением на мобильных устройствах. Если просто масштабировать окно браузера, то всё работает так, как и нужно, но если зайти на сайт с мобильного устройства, то всё отображается не так. В чём может быть проблема?
[image: Масштабирование окна браузера]

[image: Отображение на мобильном устройстве(инструменты разработчика)]

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что происходит именно не так. У вас подобная строка __<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">__ в разметке в <head> прописана?

Comment: Полагаю, что под телефоном подразумевается Iphone 5. Прописали <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> ?

Comment: Я прописал в теге meta эти значения и всё заработало, спасибо!